# Tell Google an alternative to an English word in a French content

Tags: seo, keywords, translation

What I want (if possible) is to use something like an `alt` attribute to my titles when they contains an English word.

Something like this:

```html
 <h1 alt='mes boutiques de jeux vidéo préférées'>
    Mes 'Gaming shop' favoris
 </h1>
```

I know `alt` tag is not what I looking for, so is there a good way to do that? To be 'that' specific when I create a title?

In France we use English words/name in French sentences, but some targets in my audience are young and have troubles in English so they will never type in Google 'gaming shop' but 'boutique de jeux vidéo'. Still I can't name the article another way for trends reasons.

Comment: I don't have experience with this language issue, but in general Google ignores text users can't see.  If there are two ways to say something you either have to trust Google to get it right, or say it twice.

Comment: That is what I thought aswell. But I wanted to be sure since the competition is hard :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to supply alt tag with  tag please read more about alt tag. Don't create website for Google create something is best for user/visitors and your website for the french language will automatically get some rank. If you would like to use multiple language then create website in multi language support.

Comment: You may be not familiar with french, but we use english words/names a lot in french sentences. So my question is in the focus to create something to my audience not aiming at google.
I do know what an alt tag is and what you can do with it, my question need more clarification sorry